# realmtasks not able to sync data after logout , re-login and kill app in realm

Tags: android, realm

After Logout and re-login the lists are not syncing , and also kill app and relaunch app but not sync data in realm database on realm object server with realm studio and data update with android studio app.
How to solve this problem, please help me . Thanks in advance.

Comment: Realm version??

Comment: realm version is  io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:4.0.0

Comment: Can you please provide me small  example of connecting android app and realm object server which sync data between app and realm object server ? I have tried demo RealmTasks app but not clear with realm functionality . Please help me out . Thanks in advance.